# Client Not Connecting to Server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client

So I have my server that looks like this

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server extends Thread {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(20000);
    }

    public void run() {

        while(true) {

            try {

                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " +
                        serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Just connected to "
                        + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                DataOutputStream out =
                        new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to "
                        + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
                server.close();
            }catch(SocketTimeoutException s)
            {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                break;
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        int port = 5000;
        try {
            Thread t = new Server(port);
            t.start();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run it, everything goes fine. I also have my client which looks like this.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

   public static void main(String [] args) {

      String serverName = "Server";
      int port = 5000;

      try {

         System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
         Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
         System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
         OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
         DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

         out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
         InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
         DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
         System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
         client.close();

      }catch(IOException e) {

         System.out.println("Error!");
      }
   }
}
```

After running my client I get this in the console.

```
Connecting to Server on port 5000

java.net.UnknownHostException: Server
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at maple.Client.main(Client.java:16)
```

Line 16 looks like this

```
Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
```

**EDIT:**

After changing to a valid server address when I run the code I only get certain statements to run and then it just times out. Why is this?

```
Waiting for client on port 5000...
Just connected to /127.0.0.1:57355
Hello from /127.0.0.1:57355
Waiting for client on port 5000...
Socket timed out!
```

Comment: When you get an exception, don't just print `"Error!"`. It is useless. Print the exception itself. And when you get an exception such as your `SocketTimeoutException` that could have arisen from either `accept()` or one of the read methods it is essential to print or log the stack trace as well. At present there isn't enough information here to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server name is assigned to the String literal `"Server"` rather than a valid host address.

Comment: Now my server times out before everything is completed, why is this?

Comment: The socket times out on the server waiting for new connections, simple as that. Have a look at [Oracles Multi-threaded server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServer.java). Notice how the server itself isnt threaded but the client connections are.

Answer (score 1):

Its timing out because in constructor you are setting a 20 sec time to live.

```
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(20000);
```

Remove this and you should be fine.